# Header info being written into file when PUT-ing to a Webdav server

Tags: python, python-requests

I have the following code:

```
    r = requests.put(
        config.get('webdav', 'url') + file_name,
        auth=(
            config.get('webdav', 'username'),
            config.get('webdav', 'password')
        ),
        files={
            "files": open(os.path.expanduser(charges_file_path), 'rb')
        }
    )
```

Which is fairly straightforward. It simply calls a `PUT` request to a webdav server, and pushes the data that is in files (plain text) to the server.

It works, except for a strange (or maybe not so strange if I am just missing something small) issue. When I do a `GET` on the file, or the file is viewed on the server directly, the file itself contains header information:

> --55e72d74a10b423590cd4faa68212192
> Content-Disposition: form-data; name="files"; filename="test_file6.txt"
>
> (file_data)
>
> --55e72d74a10b423590cd4faa68212192--

I haven't been able to find a reason or way around this. When I cURL the file from command line, it works fine.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I am not really familiar with how Python `requests` works, but after reading through some docs and finding a similar issue someone had with sending files to Zendesk ([this post](https://support.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115007034787-Python-file-upload-requests-adds-Content-to-files)), you might want to try using the `data` (or `json`) parameter instead of `files` in your request. Also, maybe attaching a `params` with filename if that's applicable here as well similar to the post I linked.

Another thing to do would be to put a `Content-Type` header on this request.

i.e.

```
requests.put(
  ...,
  headers={'Content-Type': 'application/binary'},
  data=open(os.path.expanduser(charges_file_path), 'rb').read()
)
```

Comment: I did, no luck.

Comment: I had a similar problem, and this led me to the solution. With regular HTTP PUT/POST operations you can use multipart form data for file uploads, but WebDAV servers generally expect the body to contain the file directly.